# OpenWeatherMap api is not responding

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am currently trying to get the data from

```
openweathermap.org
```

by **City ID**. But I am not able to get anything. I think I might have done something wrong because I am just a beginner and trying ajax for the first time.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Your Weather</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <h1>The Weather</h1>
            <div>
                <p>
                    <span id="show-weather"></span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="custom.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function getCurrentWeather() {
        $.ajax({
           url: 'http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather/' ,
           jsonp: 'jsonp',
           data: {
               id: '2172797',
               appid: 'b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1'
           },
           type: "GET",
           dataType: "jsonp"

        })
        $done(function(json) {
            $('#show-weather').text(json.coord.lon);
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: The `appid` is not a valid string, try surrounding it with quotes.

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser's developer tools?

Comment: @robertklep: `appid` is valid. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42396151/6381711), is the solution to the challenge above using it.

Comment: @nyedidikeke the `appid` _was_ invalid, OP changed their post :)

Comment: @robertklep: noted. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using JSONP in my opinion is a hack.

Using the comprehensive approach below, you can easily consume the Open Weather Map API:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            id: '2172797',
            appid: 'b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1'
        },
        url: 'https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather/',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: false
        },
        headers: {},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('error');
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks man! It's running now. Can you explain in brief though?

Comment: @PrateekGogia: First of all, you had `$done` which is not a defined function and will make you run into the `Uncaught ReferenceError: $done is not defined` error. You should rather use `.done`. Secondly your `jsonp: 'jsonp',` will run with a callback, making you run into the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`.  In short, your code should work with `.done` instead of `$done` and without `jsonp: 'jsonp',`. Note that the `dataType: "jsonp"` in your code is not relevant in this instance and may as such be simply removed.

Answer (score -1):

The keyword you are looking for is 'asynchronous programming': The `jQuery.ajax()` function finishes executing before the answer from the server arrives. Therefore, you have to tell the function beforehand what should happen at that later point in time.

The properties object you give as a parameter has a special key for that: `success`. Its value must be a function to execute when the server has answered.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function getCurrentWeather() {
        $.ajax({
           url: 'http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather/' ,
           jsonp: 'jsonp',
           data: {
               id: '2172797',
               appid: 'b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1'
           },
           type: "GET",
           dataType: "jsonp",
        }).done(function(json) {
           $('#show-weather').text(json.coord.lon);
       };
    }
});
```

Comment: I just tried this code too. As a Matter of fact, I already knew this and I tried this too. But I am still unable to get any output.

Comment: Oh, you're using jQuery 3. `success` has been removed in favor of the Promise pattern. You were almost there: `.done()` instead of `$done`. Code updated.